# How do I change the file extension with TextEdit on osx?

Tags: macos, textedit

I am teaching Python to the people I work with, and we are all mac users. I would like to be able to create files like `hello.py` or `data.csv`.

However, I do not see an option in TextEdit to save as a "plain text no-frills no-formatting non-rtf" file. When I select RTF but try to save with a .py or .csv extension, TextEdit will no do so.

Is there another text editor that comes with osx that I can use? Or, is there a way to coerce TextEdit to behave like Windows Notepad (when it comes to file extensions, etc?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TextEdit has separate plain text and rich text modes. You'll have to select Format > Make Plain Text  or set the default format to plain text first.

[image]

Comment: wow. I totally missed this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toggle command <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. This will turn rich text to plain text. Or plain text to rich text depending on which mode you are using currently. Another user has given the answer, I wanted to add the shortcut keys.

[image]